# android search widget menu item

Tags: android, search

I use this code as [this Android API Guides](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#UsingSearchWidget) suggest to have a search widget in android 3.0 or more:

```
   @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the options menu from XML
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // Do not iconify the widget; expand it by default

    return true;
}
```

I have declared search menu item (and other menu item) in res/menu/menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/help"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"
        android:title="Help" 
        />
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="Search" 
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />
</menu>
```

I also created an activity for search results and its res/xml/searchable.xml settings, as API Guides suggest.
But as I start my app i get a `NullPointerException` at`onCreateOptionsMenu`and at `onCreatePanelMenu`

Comment: You forgot that your `menu_search` item needs  `android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"`. Try adding that and see if it works. If not, make sure to attach your LogCat stack trace as an edit to your question.

Comment: OK thanks I solved using your hint.

Answer (score 1):

As @A--C said, You forgot that your menu_search item needs `android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView`
Try adding that and see if it works. If not, make sure to attach your LogCat stack trace as an edit to your question.